# Change page according to fetched GET Parameters

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to write plugin which has the ability to change the start page according to a get parameter:

The following code is the full plugin.

```
function GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter() {
if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }

if(!($_SESSION['start'])){
$_SESSION['start']=$_GET['view'];
    }
    else{}


}

add_action( 'init', 'GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter');


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'redirect_another_homepage');
function redirect_another_homepage(){
$front_page_slug=$_SESSION['start'];
$front_page_id=get_page_by_path($front_page_slug);
$content = $content.$front_page_id->ID;
if(is_home()){
$page=get_permalink($front_page_id->ID);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location.href = "<?php echo $page;?>";
//–>
</script>
<?php
}else{}}
```

I thought it was working yesterday but maybe it just look like it was working.

I also could put you as contributor in WordPress plugin repository.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what precisely you mean by "start page"? It's not WordPress terminology.

Comment: normally you set a homepage or your blog post are the front page. so intead of this another page according to the get parameter

Comment: But that's not what your code does, it seems to attempt to _redirect_ to different location altogether?

Comment: but this is why it should do it only on if(is_home())

Comment: `is_home()` is **not the home page**. It returns true on the **blog posts index**. For the site front page specifically, use `is_front_page()`.

Comment: Please **edit you question** to explain *what you expect to happen*, what's *not happening as expected*, or what's *happening unexpectedly*. "It's not working" isn't sufficient detail for us to help you. We need to know how it's intended to work, and how the current code is behaving.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the template_redirect hook.  I needed to change your code a bit for my own readability:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Homepage redirect for SEOT
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Version: 0.0.1
Author: Douglas L Sesar
Author URI: 
License: GPLv2
*/



function GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter() {

    if (!session_id()):
            session_start();
    endif;

    if(!($_SESSION['start'])):
        $_SESSION['start']=$_GET['view'];
    endif;

}

add_action( 'init', 'GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter');


add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_another_homepage');

function redirect_another_homepage(){

    $front_page_slug=$_SESSION['start'];

    $front_page_id=get_page_by_path($front_page_slug);


    $content = $content.$front_page_id->ID;

    if(is_home()):

        $page=get_permalink($front_page_id->ID);

        wp_redirect( $page );
        exit();

    endif;

}
```

I did not check your session logic, but I think this should work for you (did not test).  It should at least give you a direction to try.

Comment: as far as I know I can't use wp_redirect() in this context. it doesn't do anything

Comment: try it with a known address string wp_redirect( 'http://'.'www.google.com' );

Comment: does not work seems it is doing nothing on template redirect. simply thinks its the wrong action hook

Comment: it is almost a copy from http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Comment: however does not work

Comment: I do use that hook on occasion and it works fine for redirection; I think you are overlooking something else.  I'm sorry I could not help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...crazy to answer my own question but here is the solution
http://wordpress.org/plugins/get-different-front-page/

Thanks for your help. Why is_home() not working in this context I still don't know.

```
function GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter() {
if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }

}

 add_action( 'init', 'GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter');
 /* The fucntion GET_Different_Page_on_front_parameter() simply starts a session,
 so that one viewer gets the same homepage every time */


add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_another_homepage_gdfp');

function redirect_another_homepage_gdfp(){

if(!($_SESSION['start'])){
        $_SESSION['start']=$_GET['view'];
    }
    else{} // this if is capturing the GET parameter of the start

$front_page_slug=$_SESSION['start'];
$front_page_id=get_page_by_path($front_page_slug);

$perma=get_permalink( $front_page_id);
if(is_front_page()){ // I still not know why is_home is not working here

     wp_redirect( $perma);
     exit();

}else{}


}
```

Comment: "*Why is_home() not working in this context I still don't know*" - because it doesn't do what you think it does. Please refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), and also [this tutorial](http://www.chipbennett.net/2013/09/14/home-page-and-front-page-and-templates-oh-my/). **TL;DR** use `is_front_page()` instead.